# How to run umap on win10 within anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda, pypi

I am trying to run the example of UMAP from their [documentation](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting.html):

```
import sklearn.datasets
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import umap

pendigits = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
mapper = umap.UMAP().fit(pendigits.data)

import umap.plot
umap.plot.points(mapper)
```

### But I am facing this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'umap.plot'`:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
10 mapper = umap.UMAP().fit(pendigits.data)
11
---> 12 import umap.plot
13 umap.plot.points(mapper)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'umap.plot'

---

```
import sys, platform, umap

print(umap.__version__)
print(platform.platform())
print(sys.version)
print(dir(umap))
```

Will give:

```
0.3.10
Windows-10-10.x.xxx-SP0
3.7.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan  7 2020, 10:48:41) [MSC v.xx 64 bit (AMD64)]
['UMAP', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'distances', 'nndescent', 'numba', 'pkg_resources', 'rp_tree', 'sparse', 'spectral', 'umap_', 'utils']
```

---

Obviously, as a workaround, one could do that, but I prefer to enjoy the rich umap plotting capabilites:

```
import umap
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

digits = load_digits()
embedding = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(digits.data)
plt.plot(embedding[:,0],embedding[:,1], 'o')
```

[image]

Comment: Did you install all the requirements for `umap.plot`? It has extra requirements listed in the docs that you have linked.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I believe so, which libraries in particular?

Comment: matplotlib
    pandas
    datashader
    bokeh
    holoviews

Comment: @FlyingTeller, yes. Maybe updating them, removing umap and then reinstalling...